# I have a keypair. How do I determine the key length?

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl

Using OpenSSL from the command line in Linux, is there some way to examine a key (either public or private) to determine the key size?

Comment: There are many different ways depending on the format of the keypair.  Were you looking at a specific format?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the size (in bytes) of a .pem RSA private key is roughly 3/4 of the size of the key length (in bits) - e.g. a 4096-bit key might be roughly 3247 bytes.  File sizes do vary though.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```
openssl rsa -in private.key -text -noout
```

The top line of the output will display the key size.

For example:

```
Private-Key: (2048 bit)
```

---

To view the key size from a certificate:

```
openssl x509 -in public.pem -text -noout | grep "Public Key"
RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
```

Comment: And if he is using DSA, or something else.  How about determining the key size from the public key(cert).

Comment: @Zoredache Yeah - I could have sworn the question said "private key" specifically; either I'm losing it or an edit beat the 5 minute timer.

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014 format requires `| grep "Public-Key"`

Answer (score 22):

The first (2048) is the bit length of the key:

```
 $ ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/rsa_key.pub 
 2048 91:1c:ae:17:16:...
```

Comment: He said 'openssl', not 'openssh'.

Comment: This would actually work on a private key generated by `openssl genrsa`.  You would probably have to point it directly to the private key file though.